# Download file from a shared folder on network using Blazor

Tags: download, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor application (Blazor Server app - .NET Core 3.1) and i want to download documents (word,excel,pdf,...) from a server shared folder (intranet application)
How can I do it? What is the best way?

Best
Stefano

Comment: Do you mean you want the user to download them? If so, navigate to the URL of the document. If you want to download it into your Blazor app then use HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in a controller class

```
[HttpGet{"DownloadFile/{pathToFileInSharedDrive}"]
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFile(string pathToFileInSharedDrive) 
{
    return File(pathToFileInSharedDrive);
}
```

Then navigate to the controller from the razor component:

```
@page "/MvcLinkExample"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<button @onclick="NavigateToMvcPage">MVC Link</button>

@code {
    private void NavigateToMvcPage()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("DownloadController/DownloadFile/somePath", true);
    }
}
```